# How to make jQuery datatables mysql php with collapse/expand option

Tags: php, html, jquery, datatables-1.10

How to make jQuery datatables collapse/expand option with mysql php

I don't want to go for ajax option because in view source fetch.php page can see data
I dont have idea to secure that. when someone that php page open can read all data. so go other method.

But somebody help me to make **collapse/expand**

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#employee_data').DataTable();  
 });
```

```html
 <?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
 $query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY ID DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>    
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <h3 align="center">Datatables Jquery Plugin with Php MySql and Bootstrap</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">  
                          <thead>  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td>Name</td>  
                                    <td>Address</td>  
                                    <td>Gender</td>  
                                    <td>Designation</td>  
                                    <td>Age</td>  
                               </tr>  
                          </thead>  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                               echo '  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["address"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["gender"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["designation"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>  
                               </tr>  
                               ';  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: You want a button or something that will collapse/expand your whole table? Or only just a column?

Comment: i Want +/- buttons `td.details-control{``background:``url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;`
`}`
`tr.shown td.details-control {`
    `background:` `url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}`

Comment: Instead of inserting code pards in comment, I suggest you to use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/) to insert the code so it'll be formatted. My question is the same. If you want + and - buttons that will show/hide the content. But what kind of content you want to show/hide? The whole table? Or just a column?

Comment: @nagy-szabolcs - sorry i want to show more columns,  like this example https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abkbg9nx/. but this example json code but i want mysql database